# How to delete the changelist history and reset the changelist change number?

Tags: perforce, perforce-stream

I've uploaded a pic of my [p4v changelists history](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jlnvo.png). What I would like is for this changelist to be number 1 under the "Change" column, basically delete the history to reset the number.

Also for the future, I would like to know how to delete all the changelists there and just a single head revision.

Comment: To delete ALL the history in your server, which I think is what you’re after, just go to the server root directory and `rm -rf *`.  If you don’t actually want to delete everything, then resetting the change counter is a really bad idea and you should explain what other less obvious goal you hope to accomplish by doing that.

Comment: If what you're after is changing the number of an existing changelist: don't.  It is *technically* possible to do this, but there is absolutely no good reason to do it, and even if you do it correctly, you will probably cause a bunch of brand new problems.